# Google Sheet ownership

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet which collects data from a Google form upon submission. Then a script connected to the sheet runs and,
1- Creates a copy of another sheet (Template) and move it to a folder.
2- Sends an email to the form submitter containing the copied sheet address.
I could transfer the ownership of both sheets to someone else (looks like the form can't be passed over) but still the new created sheets keep me as the owner and the email is being sent from my account. What did I miss?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Just because you pass ownership of a file to someone else, doesn't mean your script will send emails from the owner's account. They would need to approve the security setting of the script.

Comment: What did you try since now? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To transfer ownership, use [setOwner(user)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setOwner(User))

Email is sent by who run the script, the one created the form submit trigger.

You could change the sender by using Alias of Gmail and set [from option](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#advanced-parameters) with `GmailApp`

Comment: Thanks, I’m going to make the mew owner creates a trigger. This makes sense